# How to ask for multiple values in too-many-relationship

Tags: swift, core-data

[image]

I want to ask the Exercise table for its Trainingdates in trainingdatesRel using Trainingdate.day/month/year. 
I want to use a predicate like this but don't get it to work.

Is it good advice to have many-to-many relationships like this or would it be better to use a mapping table in between?

```
        var dontAdd = false
        // check if trainingdate already existst
        let fetchRequest1 = NSFetchRequest(entityName: kExercises)
        fetchRequest1.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY trainingdatesRel.day==%i && ANY trainingdatesRel.month==%i && ANY trainingdatesRel.year==%i",day,month,year)
        fetchRequest1.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
        let results1 = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest1, error: nil) as! [Trainingdates]
        if results1.count > 0 {
            dontAdd = true
        }
```

Comment: In what sense does it not work?

Comment: Why don't you fetch the appropriate dates and then combine all the exercises from their relationships? Using a many-to-many relationship without a specific limitation on the match will lead to invalid date constructs in this case (hopefully that makes some sense)

Comment: The error is that I get too many results with this. I want a predicate that says: "Give me all trainingdatesRel where trainingdayRal.day = myDay AND trainingdayRel.month = myMonth AND trainingdayRel.year = myYear".

Comment: Why I don't fetch them and combine the relationships? It takes too long. This function will be executed many many times and I want it speed-optimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that CoreData evaluates each of those ANY clauses separately.  So, for example, if you were looking for 30 August 2015, it will check whether it has any `Trainingdates`:

- on the 30th (of any month/year), and
- in August (any day/year) and
- in 2015 (any day/month).

But the `Trainingdate` that matches each might be different.  If an `Exercise` had `Trainingdates` on **30** July 2013, 1 **August** 2014 and 2 June **2015**, it would match.

You need instead to use SUBQUERY; it will then evaluate all the conditions on each `Trainingday` in one go:

```
    fetchRequest1.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(trainingdatesRel, $date, $date.day==%i && $date.month==%i && $date.year==%i).@count > 0", day,month,year)
```

Here `$date` is a placeholder representing each `Trainingdate` (from the `trainingdatesRel` relationship) in turn.